# SQL query check if all previous rows in group meet condition

Tags: sql

I'm looking into solving following issue.

I have a table containing 6 rows (approval levels) for each int_id (request) with each own appr_id (approval status) for each user.
I can't find out how to check if all user's before approval level of active user have approved the request.

Here's an example - sample data tables:

```
drop table if exists #approvals

create table #approvals 
(
    int_id int, 
    appr_lvl int,  
    role_id int, 
    user_id int, 
    appr_name nvarchar(max), 
    appr_date float, 
    appr_id int
)

insert into #approvals (int_id, appr_lvl, role_id, user_id, appr_name, appr_date, appr_id)
values (2260, 1, 18, 132, 'auto approved', 45281.6722664352, 1),
       (2260, 2, 7, 158, 'approved', 45281.6305555556, 2),
       (2260, 3, 2, 153, 'not approved', 0, 4),
       (2260, 4, 6, 69, 'not approved', 0, 4),
       (2260, 5, 8, 126, 'not approved', 0, 4),
       (2260, 6, 18, 132, 'auto approved', 45281.6722664352, 1);

select *
from #approvals
```

Example cases:

- Running query with user_id 153 should return int_id 2260, because user_id 153 is on 3rd appr_lvl, his appr_id is 4 (=not approved) and appr_lvls 1-2 have appr_id < 3
- Running query with user_id 80 should not return any int_id as user's is not in approval list
- Running query with user_id 69 should not return any int_id as appr_lvls 1-3 not all have appr_id < 3

I tried solving it with grouping on int_id and counting rows with appr_lvls 1-3 + comparing with appr_lvl, but didn't really have any success.

Comment: Hi Andrey, I figure the downvotes are coming from lack of clarity. I read this slowly a few times and am still not sure what the goal is. So include if (1) For a given record X, all records with appr_lvl < X.appr_lvl have appr_id < X.appr_lvl AND (2) There exists a record with appr_lvl = X.appr_id and appr_name = 'not approved'. All records not satisfying conditions (1) and (2) will be excluded

Comment: Add a tag for the db,s used. and also _specify_ the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still wary that I understand the request. But this is a query that implements the logic I described in the above comment.

Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/obVyX8P_ . With your test cases demoed.

```
drop table if exists #approvals

create table #approvals 
(
    int_id int, 
    appr_lvl int,  
    role_id int, 
    user_id int, 
    appr_name nvarchar(max), 
    appr_date float, 
    appr_id int
)

insert into #approvals (int_id, appr_lvl, role_id, user_id, appr_name, appr_date, appr_id)
values (2260, 1, 18, 132, 'auto approved', 45281.6722664352, 1),
       (2260, 2, 7, 158, 'approved', 45281.6305555556, 2),
       (2260, 3, 2, 153, 'not approved', 0, 4),
       (2260, 4, 6, 69, 'not approved', 0, 4),
       (2260, 5, 8, 126, 'not approved', 0, 4),
       (2260, 6, 18, 132, 'auto approved', 45281.6722664352, 1);

select *
  from #approvals cur
 where not exists
         (
           select 1
             from #approvals lower_approval_level
            where cur.appr_lvl > lower_approval_level.appr_lvl
              and lower_approval_level.appr_id > cur.appr_lvl - 1
         )
   and exists
         (
           select 1
             from #approvals curs_approver
            where cur.appr_id = curs_approver.appr_lvl
              and curs_approver.appr_name = 'not approved'
         );
```

Comment: thanks, it's working great. Posted solution I found myself as well

Answer (score 0):

that's how I solved it. For anyone not understanding what's the purpose, it's simple. It's consequential approval flow, which follows the rule - every next approval should be possible only in case all previous approval levels have approval id < 3 (auto-approved/approved)

```
select int_id
from (select t.int_id
                ,t.appr_lvl
                ,case when t.appr_id > 2 then 1 else 0 end as appr_id
        from #approvals t
        join (select t.int_id
                        ,t.appr_lvl
                from #approvals t
                where t.user_id = @user_id and t.appr_id = 4) i on i.int_id = t.int_id
                                                                    and i.appr_lvl > t.appr_lvl) j
group by int_id
having sum(appr_id) = 0
```